# Обратится к элементу массива AJAX

Tags: ajax

Из php файла передаю массив.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В функции вывожу переданный массив[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На странице выводит как массив[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
, 
а при обращении (alert(response[0])) не показывает значение элемента
Как правильно обратиться к элементу массива?

Answer (score 1):

```
  ...
  echo json_encode($error);
?>

...
dataType: 'json', // !!!
...
success: function(response) {
  console.log(typeof response, response);
}
```

Comment: Как только добавляю в DataType формат json, функция success не срабатывает.
В моём случае срабатывает функция error

Comment: вам написали что php-часть должна JSON-кодировать ответ

Comment: Прошу прощения, пропустил.
Всё работает, спасибо.

Вопрос закрыт.